# Bug or feature in EXCEL 2010 / MS ACCESS

Tags: excel

Im using in a excel table a function   `=LEFT(C$,4)`  to copy a few characters from one col to another. if I try to import these file to MS ACCESS this fields are empty.
Did not find a option inside access to import the values from  the excel tab correctly.
Any solution for that issue ?

Comment: Just to check: the Access field you want to import it to is a text field, is it? Else the import would result in a Type Conversion error and you'd end up with a blank field instead of the text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MS-Access does not like formulas from other programs in a table.  For that functionality you would have to import the information with out the formula and then perform an expression in a field to do the same. You can do this by adding a field to a table and then in the SQL builder use the built in functions to accomplish the "Left" feature.  This would be located in the Built in functions > Text folders.

Comment: Thanks for the note. I store the XLS as *.txt and than way back to *.xls and finally import into access. This looks like a bug and not like a feature to me

Comment: Was the formula still there after the .txt then back to .xls conversion?

Answer (score 0):

Works fine for me: save the file as an xls and then File - External Data - Import from access.